# Why does declaring a variable in the console output 'undefined' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, console, undefined

```
var a = "happy";
// -> undefined
```

This is code from the console. Why when we declare anything like `var a = "happy"` in the console after clicking the enter the next line , why it showing undefined?

What is happing in the console?

Comment: The console is outputting the response from the command you entered in to it. Declaring a variable has no response, so you see `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the operation doesn't return anything. It simply stores a value in a variable and doesn't compute a result to display in the console. This is very similar to a call to a function with an empty return statement or no return statement at all. In order to access the stored value, you will need a second line simply saying `a;`. Beside, the use of `var` is now deprecated and I would advise using `let` instead.

Comment: This is an **often-repeated** duplicate question. Please don't post answers to duplicates. :-)